# display tax in woocommerce invoice

Tags: woocommerce, invoice

Unfortunately woocommerce doesn't display its invoices the way it is supposed to be in Germany. Right now it's

```
product name - quantity - price
```

I need the invoice mail template to say

```
product name - *single price* - *tax rate (e.g. 19%)* - quantity - price
```

I know I have to put this into

```
/my-theme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php
```

somewhere here:

```
<?php
/**
 * Email Order Items
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     2.0.3
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $woocommerce;

foreach ($items as $item) :

    // Get/prep product data
    $_product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );
    $item_meta = new WC_Order_Item_Meta( $item['item_meta'] );
    $image = ($show_image) ? '<img src="'. current(wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $_product->id ), 'thumbnail')) .'" alt="Product Image" height="'.$image_size[1].'" width="'.$image_size[0].'" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-right: 10px;" />' : '';

    ?>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; word-wrap:break-word;"><?php

            // Show title/image etc
            echo    apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_product_image', $image, $_product, $show_image);

            // Product name
            echo    apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_product_title', $item['name'], $_product );

            // SKU
            echo    ($show_sku && $_product->get_sku()) ? ' (#' . $_product->get_sku() . ')' : '';

            // File URLs
            if ( $show_download_links && $_product->exists() && $_product->is_downloadable() ) {

                $download_file_urls = $order->get_downloadable_file_urls( $item['product_id'], $item['variation_id'], $item );

                $i = 0;

                foreach ( $download_file_urls as $file_url => $download_file_url ) {
                    echo '<br/><small>';

                    $filename = woocommerce_get_filename_from_url( $file_url );

                    if ( count( $download_file_urls ) > 1 ) {
                        echo sprintf( __('Download %d:', 'woocommerce' ), $i + 1 );
                    } elseif ( $i == 0 )
                        echo __( 'Download:', 'woocommerce' );

                    echo ' <a href="' . $download_file_url . '" target="_blank">' . $filename . '</a></small>';

                    $i++;
                }
            }

            // Variation
            echo    ($item_meta->meta) ? '<br/><small>' . nl2br( $item_meta->display( true, true ) ) . '</small>' : '';

        ?></td>
        <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo $item['qty'] ;?></td>
        <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php if ($show_purchase_note && $purchase_note = get_post_meta( $_product->id, '_purchase_note', true)) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $purchase_note); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Can you change the output to be like this

```
product name - *single price* - *tax rate (e.g. 19%)* - quantity - price
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can display single item price exclusive of tax by adding the following line:

```
<td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo $order->get_item_total( $item, false ); ?></td>
```

just above this line:

```
<td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo $item['qty'] ;?></td>
```

This, however, will add additional column so you must add this column to other rows as well (table head and totals). To do so, open each of email templates that include this table and add this line:

```
<th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Price (excl. tax)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
```

just below this line:

```
<th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
```

Also change this line:

```
<th scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
```

into this:

```
<th scope="row" colspan="3" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
```

Now, displaying order/item tax this way would be hard as WooCommerce orders may have multiple different taxes applied. You may, however, hardcode it into the template.

You may wish to give [WooCommerce PDF Invoice](http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-pdf-invoice/5951088?ref=RightPress) plugin a try - it has an option to display prices/subtotals exclusive of tax, then tax rows, then total inclusive of tax.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit old but: Just change the tax name in woocommerce->settings->tax from `Mwst.` to `Mwst. (19%)` and so on