# display item price (not item total) in woocommerce emails

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I need to display the item price in emails sent to admin and to customers using WooCommerce. 
The default templates display Item, Quantity, and Price (item price X quantity). I can add the columns to the tables, but don't know how to get the data from the product.
(It is interesting that this has not been included in the default. I dont think i've ever placed an order online that did not include the single item price.)

This post was helpful, but didn't give me quite all needed:
[display tax in woocommerce invoice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361379/display-tax-in-woocommerce-invoice)

Comment: Try to include some code that shows the error.

Comment: There really isn't an error, it is a field which needs to be added to a table in the email template.

Answer (score 6):

It has been a while but this may come handy to someone else.

As far as I am aware, there is no method that returns the unit price, but you can just calculate it by dividing the total price of the item by its quantity like so:

```
$item->get_total() / $item->get_quantity()
```

Since this will return just a number, you would probably want to add a currency symbol, so, you would end up with something like this:

```
<?php echo wc_price($item->get_total() / $item->get_quantity()); ?>
```

Comment: I've searched for the unit price in tables "woocommerce_order_items" as "woocommerce_order_itemmeta" and did not found it. I think I'm going with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I edited plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-items.php
After product name I inserted the price:

```
 <br/>
   <strong><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>:</strong>

   <?php echo apply_filters(    'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
```

NB! I put my custom files in directory mytheme/woocommerce/emails/  - without "templates" folder (!). Strange but it's the only way to force them working.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [@Anunja](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23426887/500249)'s code up above may no longer work - instead just add the following line underneath Product Name in a copied version of templates/emails/email-order-items.php

```
echo '<br/>Individual Price $' . $_product->get_price();
```

Comment: Note if the price is modified by a plugin, for example changed to a discounted price this will show the original price.